# Is it possible to contain a rectangular image within a circle in CSS with NO clipping?

Tags: css

I would like to display arbitrary rectangular images within a circle and have them display as large as they will fit.

I am using `border-radius` to make an image (or it's container) circular. The problem with this is `object-fit: contain` only takes account of the rectangular bounding box, not the circular area so the images are cropped by the circle rather than fitting within it.

The best I have acheived so far is scaling all images by 70%. This makes any image fit without clipping, even a completely square image.

[image: square]

However this means the taller or wider the images get the more space there is between them and the edge (making them look too small).

[image]

What I really want is this...

[image]

Is this kind of "containing" possible in CSS/HTML, or only in Javascript?

Comment: Basically, no it's not possible without JS.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's possible without knowing at least the image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Can't do that without knowing the aspect ratio of the image and CSS doesn't have a way to find that. (There are ways to approximate the math needed, but it all hinges on the image's aspect ratio.)

Comment: @Paulie_D it's possible with CSS ;)

Comment: @Ouroborus you can do it even without knowing the ratio (check the duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have doubts that that solution will work in this situation. In the "duplicate", the circle is created around the box (the circle is dependent on the box). In this question, the goal is to create a box inside a circle (the box is dependent on the circle). I don't think the solutions to the former can be applied to the later.